# How can i add new branch to target file github

Tags: github, repository, branch, translation, pull-request

I want to translate a github file and commit, then make a pull request. but im not sure if i send a new branch to main(like "new-patch --> main"), is my codes join the main branch and combine them? cause if its like that i dont wanna do that because the people want to read english in master branch. i dont want to change the master file, unlike i wanna create new branch and add the new translation there. how i can do that please help?

i did make a turkish translation file, i send pull request. i expected my new branch add to main project like what it is(just think, i want 2 branch, main branch staying like origin(default), and there is a new branch that has changed by me). but instead, i guess, that branchs feature added to main branch(and didnt create new branch).